# Copy wireless network connections for multiple users - Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, networking, wireless-networking, 3g, gnome-terminal

I have a remote ubuntu box running 10.04 that connects to the internet using a 3G wireless dongle (Huawei E1762). This connection is up and running for one of the users on the machine, however the other users do not have access to the connection.

I would like to know how I can copy the network details to the other users on the machine, or set up a new connection from the terminal. From what I have found, they are stored within:

```
~/.gconf/system/networking/connections
```

However I believe copying this connection will not suffice as it will most likely require credentials stored in the user keyrings.

Any suggestions? I can only access the machine via ssh. If I can solve this it will save me going for a drive to the remote location.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I may not have a certain answer but I think that I could point you in the right direction. It sounds to me like you need to add the other users to whatever user group is required to access the dongle.

```
useradd -G {group-name} username
```

is the command to do that. You would have to figure out what user group you are required to be a part of to use that device.

A good way to tell if I am correct in assessing the problem would be to try and login as root and see if the root user can access the device.